# With Bixby, how does my spoken output vary if the device is in hands free mode

Tags: bixby

When using Bixby, I know if the user uses "Hi Bixby" versus the Bixby button, they are in hands-free mode and may not be able to see the screen. How do I vary my spoken output to accommodate this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the $handsFree EL variable or the handsFree variable available in $vivContext in Javascript to detect if the mode is hands free. Example code for showing longer/different speech in hands-free mode using EL is below (this is a Dialog - can do the same in a message in a view)

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: HelpScreen
  if ($handsFree) {
    template("Help Header text") {
      speech ("Long help wording because user is hands-free")
    }} else {
    template("Help Header text") {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing it two different ways -- one verbose:

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: Content
  if ($handsFree) {
    choose (Random) {
      template ("Listen to this quote.") {
                       speech ("Listen to this quote. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("I found this quotation.") {
        speech ("I found this quotation. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's a result from Unix fortune.") {
                       speech ("Here's a result from Unix fortune. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's one.") {
                       speech ("Here's one. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's what I found.") {
                       speech ("Here's what I found. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Listen to this quotation.") {
                       speech ("Listen to this quotation. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's one I found.") {
                       speech ("Here's one I found. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's a quote.") {
                       speech ("Here's a quote. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Here's a quotation.") {
                       speech ("Here's a quotation. #{value(text)}")}
      template ("Check this out.") {
                       speech ("Check this out. #{value(text)}")}
  }
  } else {
    choose (Random) {
      template ("Look at this quote.")
      template ("I found this quotation.")
      template ("I ran the fortune command and got this.")
      template ("Here's one.")
      template ("Here's what I found.")
      template ("Here's a good one.")
      template ("Here's one I found.")
      template ("Here's a quote.")
      template ("Here's a quotation.")
}
}
}
```

and another much less so:

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: Content
  if ($handsFree) {
      template ("\n\n") {
         speech ("<speak>#{value(text)}</speak>")
  }
  } else {
}
}
```